# Tensorflow Dataset API: Gradient is "None"?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, gradient

I've got problems with the Tensorflow Dataset API.
I'd like to pass some per-sample parameters, but I am unable to optimize them.

```
sample_data = tf.placeholder(...)
design = tf.placeholder(...)

mixture_prob = tf.Variable(..., shape=[num_mixtures, num_samples])

# transpose to get 'num_samples' to axis 0:
mixture_log_prob_t = tf.transpose(tf.log(mixture_prob, name="mixture_log_prob"))
assert mixture_log_prob_t.shape == [num_samples, num_mixtures]
```

Here is the cause of my problem:
I've got some sample data together with a design matrix. 
Also, each sample has got 'num_mixtures' parameters which I'd like to optimize.

```
data = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((
    sample_data,
    design,
    mixture_log_prob_t
))
data = data.repeat()
data = data.shuffle(batch_size * 4)
data = data.apply(tf.contrib.data.batch_and_drop_remainder(batch_size))

iterator = data.make_initializable_iterator()

batch_sample_data, batch_design, batch_mixture_log_prob = iterator.get_next()
batch_mixture_log_prob = tf.transpose(batch_mixture_log_prob)
```

Now, when running "optimizer.gradient()" I get "None" for this parameter:

```
>>> model.gradient
[(None, <tf.Variable 'mixture_prob/logit_prob:0' shape=(2, 2000) dtype=float32_ref>), ...]
```

Comment: Please provide a complete, reproducible example.

Comment: I will try, but it's really hard to put this into a short script...

Comment: So you'd like to backprop through a `Dataset`. It's an interesting feature request, but pretty niche. I'd do the slicing yourself with [random_uniform](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/random_uniform), or potentially you could put the indices in a `Dataset`, pull them out and slice then. As long as you slice along the first dimension, the gradient should stay sparse.

Comment: Yes, that's what I'd like to do.
Putting an index vector into the Dataset works great, although it is not as clean as having it directly inside the Iterator.
Thanks for the hint.